# Designing RESTful web services with XMPP servers

Tags: web-services, rest, xmpp, ejabberd

We have a website which uses HTML, angular in the front end and java in the back-end. We use RESTful webservices to perform read and write operations to the back-end, as we have IOS and Android apps too. We have messaging service in our website and apps, I am trying to make it as fast as possible. I am doing some research and came along XMPP servers for faster messaging. Can I develop RESTful web services for XMPP servers? and which language and environment is best to do it?.

Thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

I believe [XMPP-FTW](https://github.com/xmpp-ftw/xmpp-ftw) is the thing you are looking for.

> This module takes away all of the XML and works by hooking to events which are passed between client and server using a transport in JSON.